# Importing data from a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to import four data fields. `Child_id`, `First_name`, `Last_name`, `Medical`. In my form it is only pulling in `child_id`:

```
<%= form_for @check_in, :url => {:controller => 'check_ins', :action => 'create' } do |f| %>
  <% @account.children.each do |child| %>
    <%= f.check_box :child_id, {:checked => 'checked', :multiple => true}, child.id.to_s %>
    <%= image_tag child.photo.url(:thumb) %>
    <span class="name"><%= child.first %>
    <%= child.last %></span><br/>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Model associations:

```
class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children    
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :check_in
end
```

This is my create method in my check_ins controller.

def create
    @check_in = CheckIn.new(params[:check_in])

```
begin
  params[:check_in] [:child_id].each do |child_id|
    unless child_id == 0.to_s
      CheckIn.new(:child_id => child_id).save!
    end
  end
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new') }
      format.json { render json: @check_in, status: :created, location: @check_in }
  end
rescue
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @check_in.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

This form is also on a show page. The checkbox is there and next to the checkbox is the information pulled from another table: `child.first`, `child.last`. But those fields I want to be selected along with the checkbox like the `child_id` is.

Right now I have a child saved in my table with an id of 8 it would pull in the 8 but the fields for `child.first` and `child.last` aren't pulling into the new table that the id is.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, by "import data field" you mean showing the attributes of child within your form?
The form looks ok to me, now it depends on things outside of this form.

I would check on the following:

- Are the fields of child indeed named `first`, `last` and `photo` as used in
  the code snippet, and opposed to those you listed in your question?
- What are the contents of `@account` and `@account.children`? You could output both on your page to check.

Comment: in case you meant "send data from browser/form to server/rails" with import - you only have a field for child_id, none for the other fields, so that would be why, but I think that's intended.

Comment: I just updated my question. A little more detail of what i'm looking at. I think your answer bento is what i'm looking for in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: sorry, now I'm even more confused what your question is:
a) how to display child info on the page in browser
b) how to transfer user input from the form to rails (and save it in the database) ?

Answer (score 0):

I only see one form tag in your form block: `f.check_box :child_id`. The other stuff like `<%= 
child.first %>` are not part of the form, even though they're within the form block.

EDIT:

There are a number of problems. First, going strictly by the way the associations are set up, CheckIn should not have child_id attribute. It has_many :children while Child belongs_to :check_in. CheckIn should not have a child_id, Child should have a check_in_id. Therefore you should be updating each selected child with a check_in_id value. I'd read up on ActiveRecord associations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Second, the way the form is rendering controls I think you're ending up with multiple checkboxes with the same name. When rails assembles the params hash it's going to ignore all but the last hash item with a particular key. So even if everything else was set up correctly you'd still only save one child to a check in. I'd watch this tutorial on nested attributes: 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast

Lastly, I don't understand what you mean when you say it's not saving child.first and child.last (aka first_name and last_name?). That information is stored in the child object already, correct? Why would that be saved elsewhere?

If all of this was working correctly you'd be able to do things like this:

```
# find an account
account = Account.find(99)

# create a check_in
check_in = CheckIn.create

# save one or more (or all) of account's children to the check_in
check_in.children << account.children

# see the first name of a child associated with a check_in
check_in.children[0].first
```

Comment: Also, if a CheckIn can have many children you should look into nested attributes. I'm not sure it's going to work the way you've set it up.

Comment: In your confusion it has brought a little insight to me. I realized now what you mean that the information being brought in isn't a part of the form. So now I understand that my issue is how to pass in the child_first and child_last as a part of the form that can be brought in along with the :child_id when the checkbox is checked. Does that help any?

Comment: It's not clear to me what it is that's getting updated when you submit the form. Can you add your model associations to the question? Describing the controller(s) and actions would help, too.

Comment: My associations are working correctly. I can pull in the child_id. I can do the first 2 things in the list of possible things after the association is properly configured. I can pull in the id from my child table into my check_in table. It's just the childs first and last name won't pull into the check_in table. Any other ideas?

Comment: I must be missing something then. You could use hidden_field tags for first and last.

Comment: The issue ends up being, from my form it is not writing to my table. It is writing the child_id to the check_in table but I cannot get it to pass in any other information. I want to also pass in a childs_first childs_last.